# Correct code formatting with sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have a large block of code. Something like this but much larger:

```
<div class="something"><div class="something-else"><p>Here is some text
</p></div></div>
```

How can I correct the indentation to make it something like this with Sublime text?:

```
<div class="something">
  <div class="something-else">
    <p>Here is some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found is the [`HTML-CSS-JS Prettify`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify) plugin from [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io). Please make sure you read all of the directions carefully, as the plugin depends on [`node.js`](http://nodejs.org), and has to be set up properly.